# few requests causes 503 errors (nginx, gunicorn, pyramid)

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, pyramid

In the (web) app I am working on - there are some longish (I guess) requests (2-4 seconds). When I run 1 or 2 of them, everything is fine, but 4-5 of them the backend responds with 503. This lasts couple of seconds. When I try to access the website during this time, sometimes the pyramid app is reporting 503 errors BUT most of the time the frontend is not even hosted (there's just a default nginx 503 error page).

Not sure what's going on... This inconsistent behavior is confusing.

Here is a part of my `config.ini`:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5000
workers = 5
timeout = 120
```

The long running operations are db queries (SQLAlchemy, Postgres).

Comment: To help troubleshoot, bump up your timeout to 1200 seconds. You will need to provide a lot more information. What is your view actually doing? How long does the raw SQL query take? Can you reproduce the issue locally in development? If so, then turn on the Pyramid debugtoolbar to help isolate what is slow in the request.

Comment: it turned out to be a problem with a varnish timeout... thx for your comment though

Answer (score 2):

Pyramid itself will never return a 503 unless you do so manually yourself. The 503 response is being generated in gunicorn or nginx based on some configuration settings you have there.

Comment: It's often done by nginx if the backend doesn't send any bytes in the response in a certain amount of time. Gunicorn may have similar settings.